# Uniqueness of linear differential equations

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, unbounded-operators

Let $A:D(A)\to H$ be a densely defined linear operator on a Hilbert space $H$, not necessarily continuous or self-adjoint. Let $v$ be a vector in $D(A)$.

> If a solution to the differential equation $\dot\varphi(t)=A\varphi(t)$; $\varphi(0)=v$ exists, is it unique?

I am not asking for a result on the existence of solutions. It is easy to see that this question is equivalent to the case $v=0$, whereas the case of continuous $A$ follows from eg the Picard Lindelöf theorem.

Comment: Is $A$ closed? In what sense does the solution exist?

Comment: A solution is a $C^1$ function $\varphi:(-\epsilon,\epsilon)\to D(A)$ so that $\frac d{dt}\varphi(t) = A\varphi(t)$. I am right now interested in general case, where no restrictions are made on $A$. But if the result changes if some weak restrictions (like $A$ being closed) are made, this is of course interesting. Actually it was basically by accident that I asked for $H$ to be a Hilbert space and not a Banach space.